# How to re-indent Python code after changing indent width in Emacs?

Tags: python, emacs

I changed `python-indent` from 3 to 4. I then `mark-whole-buffer` and `indent-for-tab-command`. It gave me garbage.

Comment: ... for me it would be `git checkout -- file`, but I'm pretty sure that's not what you're wanting ...

Comment: It does work when you `mark-whole-buffer` and then indent when the python-indent equals 3 setting?

Comment: @Dualinity Yes, but maybe because it is already perfectly 3-space indented.

Comment: Could you maybe try to add some extra and remove some spaces and then see if it still works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the `indent-region` function. So I'd try mark the whole buffer, then `M-x` and type `indent-region`. It's usually bound to `C-M-\`, as far as I know.

**Edit**

Re-indentation does not work for a `tab-width` change. As I wrote in the comments changing spaces to tabs and then altering the `tab-width` is a solution:

"Guessing you are indenting with space and not tabs, you'd first do `tabify` on the buffer content with your `tab-width` set to 3. Then change `tab-width` to 4 and run `untabify`."

Comment: Hm, another attempt. Guessing you are indenting with space and not tabs, you'd first do `tabify`on the buffer content with your `tab-width` set to 3. Then change `tab-width` to 4 and run `untabify`, maybe this does the trick.

Comment: It works :). You should write it as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Changed the answer to include solution, you could accept now ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of a hack, but it won't give you the garbage that `indent-region` is giving you

1) Make sure tabs as spaces are set to 4 spaces. In a scratch buffer type:

```
(setq tab-width 4)
```

And then evaluate it by marking it and using `M-x eval-region`

2) Globally replace all sets of three spaces with a tab character

```
M-x replace-regexp [SPC][SPC][SPC][RET] C-q[TAB][RET]
```

3) Highlight the whole buffer and untabify

```
M-x mark-whole-buffer M-x untabify
```

This will convert all tabs into four spaces.

Comment: Are you sure there should be 4 times `[SPC]`? If so, why? First, change 4 spaces to a `TAB`, then change all tabs back to 3 spaces.

Comment: Ack, I had this backwards. I was going from four to three, not three to four. Good catch. Fixing it now.

Comment: If it's not working, OP might have to also eval the elisp expression `(setq default-tab-width 4)`. I have tested this though, and it should work so long as there aren't any incorrectly indented blocks to start with.

Comment: An ordinary replace (instead of replace-regexp) is good enough since the search and replacement terms are both ordinary

Answer (score 0):

Try `indent-region` instead on the buffer. Initially bounded to `C-M-\`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but it worked for me as a quick work-around: to a "M-X replace-string", "   " -> "    ". Then you have to close and re-open if your emacs does an automatic idnent-detection on the file. Then you have to go through and fix mult-line code (with tab), and strings that have lots of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This might also help:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingPython

In particular, [PythonTidy](http://lacusveris.com/PythonTidy/) is very effective for restructuring messy code, with minor hiccups (unfortunately the tool is not easy to configure):

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs#toc17

Answer (score 0):

May be it will not be useful or not by theme, but I use such script.
Run it from command line. (python reindent.py some.py)

Change string_equal, and replace_to.

```
import sys

file_name = sys.argv[1]
string_equal = "   "
replace_to =  "    "

with open(file_name) as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    f.close()

def create_new_line(i):
    new_line = ""
    flag = True
    cur_s = ""
    for k in i:
        if flag and k == " ":
            cur_s += k
            if cur_s == string_equal:
                new_line += replace_to
                cur_s = ""
        else:
            flag = False
            new_line += k
    return new_line

with open(file_name, "w") as f:
    for i in data:
        l = create_new_line(i)
        f.write(l)
    f.close()
```